# Why does Azure container apps "Network In bytes" never goes lower than 10 kbps while hosting an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-container-apps

I've created an Azure container app which is running a container image of an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project.

I'm trying to get my app into an idle state so the costs are a fraction of active state billing as stated in the billing documentation of Azure container apps, the problem is that the application has always a "Network In Bytes" metrics of no less than 10 kbps, despite the cpu readings being near 0.

I understand that part of that network ingress is due to the nature of the application, although the metrics shown in docker desktop for the same image shows network traffic of no more than 1kbps.

Is there any way to ensure that a Web API application has network ingress of less than 1kbps when its in idle state for azure container apps and containers in general?

Examples of metrics show by Azure:

Network ingress in bytes time period from 10:21am to 11:21am

[Network ingress metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbtq2.png)

Cpu usage time period from 10:21am to 11:21am

[Cpu usage metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KPSY.png)

I tried searching for ways of limit network ingress while the app was not processing any request, I didn't find anything regarding this topic.

Also tried configuring a idle timeout for the kestrel server so it would stop all together while the container was still running, although that's not a feasible solution anyway.

Comment: The Azure Container Apps billing doc states that idle usage charges might apply when a container app's revision is running with a minimum replica count greater than zero & scaled to the minimum replica count.

Comment: A replica is considered idle when all of the following conditions are true: the replica is running in a revision that is currently eligible for idle charges, all of the containers in the replica have started and are running, the replica isn't processing any HTTP requests, the replica is using less than 0.01 vCPU cores, and the replica is receiving less than 1,000 bytes per second of network traffic. When a replica is idle, resource consumption charges are calculated at the reduced idle rates. When a replica isn't idle, the active rates apply.

Comment: However, the Azure Load Balancer has a default idle timeout setting of four minutes, which means that App Service returns a timeout to the client if the application does not return a response within approximately 240 seconds (230 seconds on Windows app, 240 seconds on Linux app). Therefore, if the ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project is not processing any HTTP requests, it is possible that the network ingress is due to the health probe requests, which are not billable.

Comment: -   [Billing in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/billing#consumption-plan)
-   [Application performance FAQs for Web Apps in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds)
-   [Monitor Azure Container Apps metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/metrics#monitor-azure-container-apps-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Container Apps billing document states that idle usage charges might apply when a container app’s revision is running with a minimum replica count greater than zero & scaled to the minimum replica count.

A replica is considered idle when all of the following conditions are true:

the replica is running in a revision that is currently eligible for idle charges
all of the containers in the replica have started and are running, the replica isn’t processing any HTTP requests
the replica is using less than 0.01 vCPU cores, and the replica is receiving less than 1,000 bytes per second of network traffic.
Usage charges are calculated individually for each replica. So when a replica is idle, resource consumption charges are calculated at the reduced idle rates. When a replica isn’t idle, the active rates apply.

The “Network In Bytes” metric for Azure Container Apps is based on the amount of network traffic received by the container app. It is not possible to limit the network ingress of a Web API application to less than 1kbps while it is in an idle state, as this is determined by the nature of the application and the traffic it receives. However, it is possible to reduce the resource consumption charges for Azure Container Apps by ensuring that the application is in an idle state.

Therefore, if you want to reduce the resource consumption charges for your Azure Container Apps, you can try to ensure that your application meets the above criteria for idle replicas.

Reference:

- [Billing in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/billing#consumption-plan)
- [Application performance FAQs for Web Apps in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds)
- [Monitor Azure Container Apps metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/metrics#monitor-azure-container-apps-metrics)